# Как обработать события для массива из N кнопок?

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте.

У меня в программе создается массив из N ImageButton. И для каждой кнопки нужно обработать событие нажатия.

```
caseLevel = new ImageButton[numLevel];
for (int i = 0; i < numLevel; i++) {
    caseLevel[i] = new ImageButton(this);
    caseLevel[i].setBackgroundResource(id[i]);
    caseLevel[i].setOnClickListener(this);
}

void onClick(View v)
{
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case caseLevel[0].getId():  <= в этом месте eclipse кричит, что выражение должно быть константой
    }
}
```

Собственно поэтому я и в замешательстве сейчас. Подскажите, как мне быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не использовать `switch`, пишите `if`.

Comment: Я написал вот таким образом, но он почему-то все действия производит с первой кнопкой, меняет background у первой кнопки, на какую бы я ни ни жал.


 public void onClick(View v)
 {
  final ImageButton bt = (ImageButton) findViewById(caseLevel[0].getId());
  for (int i = 0; i < numLevel; i++)
   if (v.getId() == caseLevel[i].getId()) {
    caseLevel[onClick].setBackgroundResource(id[onClick]);
    onClick = i;
    caseLevel[i].setBackgroundResource(idC[i]);
    break;
   }
 }

Comment: вероятно потому что у ваших элементов у всех id = NO_ID. Надо установить при создании id, все будет работать.

Comment: спасибо, это помогло :)

Answer (score 2):

Используйте следуюшую форму. Надеюсь это вам поможет

```
caseLevel = new ImageButton[numLevel];
for (int i = 0; i < numLevel; i++) {
    caseLevel[i] = new ImageButton(this);
    caseLevel[i].setBackgroundResource(id[i]);
    final int iterator = i;
    caseLevel[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View sender)
        {
            ...iterator...
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
switch(v.getId()) {
    case caseLevel[0].getId() - должно быть константным выражением
}
```

[The switch Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) - подробнее.

В вашем случае было бы правильно использовать ресурсные константы вида R.id.button1 в case выражении.

Comment: К сожалению, я не могу использовать ресурсные константы, ибо у меня каждый раз количество кнопок будет меняться, поэтому нужно создавать их массивом.

Answer (score 1):

при создании imagebutton регистрируйте его в мапе вместе с хендлером который будет обрабатывать событие. напр:

```
Map<ImageButton, ActionHandler> handlers = new HashMap <ImageButton, ActionHandler>();

// интерфейс для обработки действия
interface ActionHandler
{
   public void handleClick(View v);
   public void handleAnotherAction(Object ...args);
}

код обработки события у image button:
public void onClick(View v)
{
    ActionHandler h = handlers.get(this);
    if (null == h) 
    {
         // do something to handle exceptional situation or use default handler    
    }    
    else 
    {
         h.handleClick(v);
    }
}
```

при создании imagebutton вам надо будет делать как-то так:

```
ImageButton b = new ImageButton();
ActionHandler handlerForButtonB = new ActionHandler()
{
  // добавляем нужный функционал
}
handlers.put(b, handlerForbuttonB);
```

p.s. если ImageButtton не стандартный клас то вы спокойно можете добавить ему поле в котором будете хранить ссылку на ActionHandler. так можно обойтись без причуд с мапой